# Issue with FILE I/O and using data within

Tags: c, file

This code for tolerance analysis compiles and runs, but the output is incorrect and I believe it to be the incorrect handling of the file and the data within the file.

The data in the file is:

```
PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V
PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V
PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F
GAP,0.000,0.080
```

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void parsePart(char input[], float*pnom, int*pinp, float*ptol, char*pFV);
void parseGap(char input[], float *pmin, float *pmax);
float meanGap(float nom[], float imp[], int size);
float tolGap(float tol[], int size);

int main()
{
    FILE *ptable;
    int i, num_of_parts;
    int impact[10];
    float nominal[10], tolerance[10];
    char FV[10];
    char input_str[30];
    float max, min, gap, tol;
    float curr_max, curr_min;

    ptable=fopen("D:\\Input.txt", "r");

    for(i=0; i<11; i++);
    {
        fgets(input_str, 30, ptable);
        if(input_str[0] == 'P')
        {
            parsePart(input_str, &nominal[i], &impact[i], &tolerance[i], &FV[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            parseGap(input_str, &min, &max);
            num_of_parts = i;

        }
    }

    gap = meanGap(nominal, impact, num_of_parts);
    tol = tolGap(tolerance, num_of_parts);
    curr_max = gap+tol;
    curr_min = gap-tol;

    printf("Gap mean is: %f inches\n", gap);
    printf("Gap tolerance is: %f inches\n", tol);

    if(fabs(max-curr_max)< 0.0001 && curr_max > (gap*2)) //they are equal
    {
        printf("The maximum gap is %f which is greater than the allowed %f\n", curr_max, gap*2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The maximum gap is %f which is within the allowed %f\n", curr_max, gap*2);
    }
    if(fabs(min+curr_min)<0.0001 && curr_min < gap-gap)
    {
        printf("The minimum gap is %f which is less than the allowed %f\n", curr_min, gap-gap);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The minimum gap is %f which is within the allowed %f\n", curr_min, gap-gap);
    }
    return 0;
}

void parsePart(char input[], float*pnom, int*pinp, float*ptol, char*pFV)
{
    int i;
    char * field[5];

    field[0]=strtok(input, ",");

    for(i=1; i<5; i++);
    {
        field[i] = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    *pnom = atof(field[1]);
    *pinp = atoi(field[2]);
    *ptol = atof(field[3]);
    *pFV = *field[4];
}

void parseGap(char input[], float *pmin, float *pmax)
{
    char *field[2];

    field[0] = strtok(input, ",");
    field[1] = strtok(NULL, ",");
    field[2] = strtok(NULL, ",");

    *pmin = atof(field[1]);
    *pmax = atof(field[2]);
}

float meanGap(float nom[], float imp[], int size)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++);
    {
        sum += nom[i]*imp[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
float tolGap(float tol[], int size)
{

    int i;
    float sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++);
    {
        sum += tol[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The output should look something like:

```
Actual Gap Mean: 0.025”
Actual Gap Tolerance: 0.085”
The Maximum Gap (0.110”) is (Greater) than specified (0.080”)
The Minimum Gap (-0.060”) is (Less) than the specified (0.000”)
```

I get a 0 for gap mean and all the other values are incredibly large numbers.

Any and all hints as to where I could be going wrong or need improvement are great. Thank you.

Comment: Why not step through your program in a debugger to trace where things start going wrong?

Comment: Check for conversion/coercion errors and undefined behaviour.

Comment: parseGap is wrongly coded.  Each field should be a string large enough to hold the longest possible value, you are currently using pointers to strings, without any associated storage.

Comment: in the code you're printing `"The minimum gap is %f which is less than the allowed %f\n"` but you're expecting `The Minimum Gap (-0.060”) is (Less) than the specified (0.000”)`? Those are completely different sentences

Comment: thats why I said "should look something like". It doesnt have to be a copy, just needs to get the same point across. @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Answer (score 0):

In line 85, `char *field[2];` should be `char *field[3];`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly arrays **impact** *et al* are sized at 10, so

```
 for(i=0; i<11; i++);
```

Is wrong for 2 reasons:

1) loop should go from 0 to 9

2) a **for** statement shouldn't have a ; after it, that terminates the whole statement.

Comment: Also **for** in **parsePart** no semicolon at end of for statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
  typedef struct{char c[6];} String;
  String field1,field2,… …;
  String *pf1,*pf2,… …;

  pf1=field1;
  pf2=field2;
  …
  …
  pf1=strtok(input,…
```

Is the correct (outline) way to code **parseGap** assuming the longest data in the input file is 5 characters long,

Comment: `strtok` returns a pointer to the token, instead of copying the token to a location in memory, so `char *pf1; pf1 = strtok(input, ",");` is enough.